# encrypted password to md5 in Admin Panel

Tags: php, encryption, md5

i have a script and its storing user password in encrypt when user register their account and when i show user all info in admin panel with password its show encrypted password but i want to show this password in my admin panel as MD5 below is the register form codes

```
if ($input->p['a'] == "submit") {
    verifyajax();
    $username = $input->pc['username'];
    $password = $input->pc['password'];
    $password2 = $input->pc['password2'];
    $fullname = $input->pc['fullname'];
    $email = $input->pc['email'];
    $email2 = $input->pc['email2'];

$inputs = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password, "fullname" => $fullname, "email" => $email, "email2" => $email2);

$newdata = array("type" => $membership_bonus, "upgrade_ends" => $membership_expires, "money" => $account_balance, "purchase_balance" => $purchase_balance, "fullname" => $fullname, "comes_from" => $_SESSION['comes_from'], "username" => $username, "password" => md5($password), "email" => $email, "ref1" => $referrer, "signup" => $signupdate, "country" => $country, "computer_id" => $computerid, "signup_ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "gateways" => $usrgateway, "umobile" => $umobile);
```

and in admin panel when i show the user password i use the below code but its show encrypted password .

```
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input name=\"email\" type=\"text\" value=\"";
echo $member['password'];
echo "\" /></td>
  </tr>
```

what should i need to do to show MD5 password in my ADMIN PANEL .

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to decrypt md5 hash? I mean do you want to show your original password? if yes the answer is md5 can not be decrypt :(

Answer (score 0):

md5 is a one way hashing so it can't be reversed

Comment: md5 is not an encryption algorithm. It is a hashing algorithm.